# Python Socket Call server.py and client.py in main.py

Tags: python, tcpclient, tcpserver, tcpsocket

My question is that how to call server and client sequentially in main method ?

Problem is that python debugger waiting and be suck in line that calling the server(blocking the calling client line).

I tried threading but not work . Thanks for your attention.

IMPORTANT: Below codes using Python2

Main python file:

```
import xClient
import xServer
import threading

tempServer=xServer

tempClient=xClient

thrMain = threading.Thread(target=tempServer.innerClient.Main())
thrMain.start()
thrMain.join()

tempClient.innerClient.Main()
```

xClient.py : # STANDARD Client code and works correctly

```
import socket
import time

class innerClient:
    def Main():
        time.sleep(2)
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        port = 12345
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((host, port))
        message = "test message"
        while True:
            s.send(message.encode('ascii'))
            data = s.recv(1024)
            print('Received from the server :', str(data.decode('ascii')))


            ans = raw_input('Continue(y/n) :')
            if ans == 'y':
                continue
            else:
                break
        s.close()
```

xServer.py : # STANDARD Server code and works correctly

```
import socket
import threading
class innerServer:
    print_lock = threading.Lock()

    # thread fuction
    def threaded(c):
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                print('See you later')
                print_lock.release()
                break
            data = data[::-1]
            c.send(data)
        c.close()

    def Main():
        host = ""
        port = 12345
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind((host, port))
        print("socket binded to post", port)
        s.listen(5)
        print("socket is listening")
        while True:
            c, addr = s.accept()
            print_lock.acquire()
            print('Connected to :', addr[0], ':', addr[1])

            thr = threading.Thread(target=threaded, args=(c,))
            thr.start()
            thr.join()
        s.close()
```

[TCP Socket Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tvR4.png)

Comment: If you call `thrMain.join()`, execution won't proceed past that line until the thread (running the server) exits.  If you want both the server and client to run at the same time you need to not join the server thread.

Comment: I tried you advice but while debugging the code it is stucking in this line of code : thrMain = threading.Thread(target=tempServer.innerClient.Main())  it can never passing even thrMain.start()  so after server calling method working  any line of code never works

Comment: `threading.Thread(target=tempServer.innerClient.Main())` means to call `Main()` *right now*, and use its result as the function to run in a thread.  Get rid of the `()`.

Comment: That is the answer you crazy coder. Thanks for your interest after a long time.